# ActiveMQ configuration

Tags: activemq-classic

[image]

I'm new to **ActiveMQ** and I'd like to know how and where to add this line of code to enable **MQTT** on my broker. I'm running broker on Mac.

Kindly help me with this configuration.

Comment: In your broker configuration

Comment: conf\activemq.xml

Comment: Thank you so much guys. One more question is do I need to replace mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883 with mqtt://localhost:1883 or let that default value be as it is ?

Comment: @Sachin since it is a server-side listening address. mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883 indicates listen on port :1883 for all network interfaces-- which is probably what you want.  "mqtt://localhost:1883" would indicate only listen on the loop back addr (127.0.0.1) or whatever 'localhost' resolves to on that system

Comment: Oh I see !. Thanks Matt that was informative.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `MQTT` protocol is supported for `ActiveMQ` when it starts if you download from [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/). Apache has configured the broker well in `/conf/activemq.xml` so that you can run it directly. Meanwhile, `openwire`, `amqp`, `stomp` and `ws` are enabled for ActiveMQ as well.

```
<transportConnectors>
    <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
    <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

Answer (score -1):

After you have create a new broker using tool `ARTEMIS_PATH/bin/artemis[.cmd in Windows]` named for example `TestBroker`, there will be broker's work path in `ARTEMIS_PATH/bin/TestBroker`.

The file that configure connectors is `broker.xml` and it will be located in `ARTEMIS_PATH/bin/TestBroker/etc/broker.xml`

Comment: The question was referring to ActiveMQ, not ActiveMQ Artemis